# How to retain the child window reference on the page reload or refresh in all the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window.open, window.closed

Use Case: In my application i have one parent window which can open many child windows. What i have done is i have opened the child window using the window.open() method. And on the click of logout using the same reference i have closed all the windows.

But there is a catch, I am not able to retain the reference of the child window. I tried to use the localStorage of HTML5 but cause of stringify Issue with the DOM objects. I am not able to get the correct reference.

I ahve also tried saving the reference in cookies. But cookies also support the string only so i got stuck again. Please help with the same as i am trying to research on the same but no fruitful result.